# how to show bootstrap edit and delete button appearing on hover over the table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a twitter bootstrap table with a button group in the last cell of each row.
I want these buttons appear only when user hovers over the row. and need click both edit and delete icons separately.

I have following scripts
html

```
<div class="nesting">

  <a href="#" class="foo-class nesting-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" area-hidden="true"></span> Foo <span class="pencil glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
  <div class="nestchild">
    <a href="#" class="nesting-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" area-hidden="true"></span> Bar<span class="pencil glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    <a href="#" class="nesting-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" area-hidden="true"></span> This is a link<span class="pencil glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    </div>    
      </div>
```

css

```
.foo-class { float:left; padding : 3px; width:300px; min-width:300px; }
.nesting span.pencil { float:right; }
.nestchild a { clear: both;display : block; }
.nesting { background-color:#ccc; width:300px;}
.nesting a {width:285px;}
.nesting a .pencil {display : none; }
.nestchild { margin-left : 15px; }
```

javascripts

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nesting a').hover(function(){  
        $(this).children('span.pencil').css({'display' : 'inline-block'});
    },function(){  
        $(this).children('span.pencil').css({'display' : 'none'});
    });
});
```

see this demo

https://jsfiddle.net/lilan2/a82jzucc/

how can I develop this properly

Answer (score 2):

Instead you can use jquery to update edit and delete buttons in table row on mouse over show edit delete buttons

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // show buttons on tr mouseover
  $(".hover tr").live("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).find("td:last-child").html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="editrow(' + $(this).attr("id") + ')">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="deleterow(' + $(this).attr("id") + ')">Delete</a>');
  }); //

  // remove button on tr mouseleave
  $(".hover tr").live("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).find("td:last-child").html("&nbsp;");
  });

  // TD click event
  $(".hover tr").live("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.nodeName == "TD") {
      alert("You can track TD click event too....Isnt it amazing !!!");
    }
  });
});
editrow = function(itemId) {
  alert("You clicked 'Edit' link with row id :" + itemId);
}
deleterow = function(itemId) {
  alert("You clicked 'Delete' link with row id :" + itemId);
}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
}

table th {
  text-align: left;
  background: #D3D3D3;
  padding: 2px;
}

table tr:hover {
  background: #EFEFEF;
}

table tr {
  text-align: left;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}

table td a {
  color: #0454B5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <table width="40%" border="0" class="hover">
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th width="20%">Action</th>
      </th>
      <tr id="100">
        <td>droid</td>
        <td>Andro</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="101">
        <td>droid</td>
        <td>Andro</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="102">
        <td>droid</td>
        <td>Andro</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="103">
        <td>droid</td>
        <td>Andro</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="104">
        <td>droid</td>
        <td>Andro</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="105">
        <td>droid</td>
        <td>Andro</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Refer updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/VaibhavD/6aehaxr6/2/embedded/result/

Comment: how can I add another name as Add to this edit and delete links

Comment: Instead of wrapping all of your answer into a code block, add the code of your jsfiddle to your answer

Comment: Table tr is resized on hover. I didn't want this !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand correctly what you want, but check out this fiddle.

You can hide pencil link on document ready or by css and then on div of class `nesting` fire `hover` event that shows `pencil` class link. On [mouseleave](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event 
hide `pencil` class link.

Then insert click event on `pencil` class inside `nesting` class div.

PS: I haven't find any delete button in your code, but it's the same principal of inserting on click on `pencil` class.

If you want to show only the pencil icon corresponding to row hover, you can use [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function on every link inside div `nesting` class

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
$('.nesting a .pencil').hide();

$('div.nesting a').each(function(){

  $(this).hover(function(){  
     $(this).find('.pencil').show();
 }).mouseleave(function(){
   $(this).find('.pencil').hide();
  });
})
  
 $('div.nesting .pencil').click(function(){
   alert("You have clicked on pencil");
 }) 
 });
```

```css
.foo-class { float:left; padding : 3px; width:300px; min-width:300px; }
.nesting span.pencil { float:right; }
.nestchild a { clear: both;display : block; }
.nesting { background-color:#ccc; width:300px;}
.nesting a {width:285px;}
.nestchild { margin-left : 15px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nesting">
    
  <a href="#" class="foo-class nesting-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" area-hidden="true"></span> Foo <span class="pencil glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
  <div class="nestchild">
    <a href="#" class="nesting-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" area-hidden="true"></span> Bar<span class="pencil glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    <a href="#" class="nesting-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" area-hidden="true"></span> This is a link<span class="pencil glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    </div>    
      </div>
```

Comment: ok I need load one pencil icon in mouse hover in table raw as an example 
   I need view only pencil icon when I visit Foo raw.

Comment: Which one of the pencil icons? Foo, Bar or This is a link?

Comment: I mean I need when I hover mouse on each foo bar or this is link I need only display one pencial icon in one times. when I hover mouse foo I need icon on foo raw then if I hover mouse this is link raw then I need pencil icon on this is link raw.

Comment: Edit answer, now pencil will show only for the corresponding row

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of a jQuery script for your case. You can do it simply with css.

Just add a `:hover` style in css

```js
function editItem() {
      alert("Edit icon clicked");
  }
```

```css
.foo-class {
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 300px;
    min-width: 300px;
}

.nesting span.pencil {
    float: right;
}

.nestchild a {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}

.nesting {
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 300px;
}

.nesting a {
    width: 285px;
}

a.nesting-item .pencil {
    display: none;
}

a.nesting-item:hover .pencil {
    display: block;
}

.nestchild {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="nesting">

    <a href="#" class="foo-class nesting-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open" area-hidden="true"></span> Foo <span class="pencil glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a>
    <div class="nestchild">
        <a href="#" class="nesting-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" area-hidden="true"></span> Bar<span class="pencil glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" onclick="editItem()"></span></a>
        <a href="#" class="nesting-item"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe" area-hidden="true"></span> This is a link<span class="pencil glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" onclick="editItem()"></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @John add the bootstrap js and css files that will work. I have updated the code.